# com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, hystrix, netflix-ribbon

I am trying microservices with eureka and zuul. And there is a problem with all requests, which take more then 1 second. As I have understood, 1 second is default hystrix timeout, and for configuring timeouts in Zuul, I have to configure these properties:

`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds`
`ribbon.ConnectTimeout` 
`ribbon.ReadTimeout`

but when I set them, there is "Cannot resolve configuration property ..." warning on each of them  in the Intelije Idea. And, it seems, they are not applied and don't work.

Answer (score 10):

Setting ribbon readTime in zuul server should solve this problem.

```
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
```

**Note**: ReadTimeout is case sensitive.

Comment: This fixed the issue .Thank You

Answer (score 7):

Add the following property in Zuul gateway service

hystrix: 
   command: 
      default: 
         execution: 
            iso lation: 
               thread: 
                  timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000

ribbon: 
   ReadTimeout: 60000
   connection-timeout: 3000
   eureka: 
      enabled: true

zuul: 
   ignoredServices: '*'
   host: 
      time-to-live: -1
      connect-timeout-millis: 5000
      max-per-route-connections: 10000
      max-total-connections: 5000
      socket-timeout-millis: 60000
   semaphore: 
      max-semaphores: 500

Comment: Thanks! Why Netflix uses two notations - ReadTimeout and connection-timeout?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer is edited**

This way you will increase Hystrix timeout (globaly):

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

or per service:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    <serviceName>:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000
```

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. and after "hystrix" available properties are only: "metrics" and "shareSecurityContext". There is no "command" property

Comment: Edited, try it now @Vados

Comment: I am getting Gateway Timeout after 3 seconds event if I have increased the `timeoutInMilliseconds` to 10000

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties of zuul server just add that variables:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 240000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout: 120000
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 120000
```

You can also refresh your project in Intellij.