# I getting always getting "{"status":504,"error":"Gateway Timeout","message":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out"}"?

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am always getting "2019-04-09 07:24:23.389  WARN 11676 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering", for request which takes more than 1 second.

I have already tried to increase the timeout but none of them worked.

2019-04-09 07:24:23.389  WARN 11676 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.error(FilterProcessor.java:105) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.error(ZuulRunner.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.error(ZuulServlet.java:145) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:83) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at ava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55465436/5953575)

Hystrix readed timeout by default is 1 second, and you can change that in your application.yaml file. It can be done globally or per service.

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is caused due to hysterix timeout.
The above issue can be solved by disabling the hystrix timeout or increasing the hysterix timeout as below :

```
# Disable Hystrix timeout globally (for all services)
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false

#To disable timeout foror particular service,
hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.timeout.enabled: false

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (per service)
hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

The above solution will work if you are using discovery service for service lookup and routing.

Here is the detailed explaination : [spring-cloud-netflix-issue-321](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/321)

Answer (score 0):

You are timing out on H2 console testing with postman or any other http testers because: Using Zuul...hysterix...you are trying to send the same exact object to the H2 database. This may be happening because you have validators on your models also. To resolve: make sure the json, xml or whatever it is objects are relatively unique by re-edit and then try to send request again.